# Advanced WordPress Custom Taxonomy on Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a client I'm creating a custom post type to handle awards they've won and so they can easily update new awards. The awards are given to many different products of theirs and also at different years. So the awards can be won multiple times. I need to list the products each award has won, as well as display the awards on a product page that correspond to that product. Fairly straight forward, except I need to also add the year the award was won. They could win the same award for the same product on different years. And they could also win the same award in the same year for multiple products. They want to be able to show all awards won in a select year, as well as be able to list all awards a product has won, including any multiples the product has won. Right now I have it set up as categories where the year is the parent and the product is the child... But this isn't elegant at all and in future years each product would have to be entered in all over again. Anyone know of a way to create a more advance taxonomy so that I can organize each award by year and product that won the award, without having to create repeat product categories in each year?

This is an example of how I have it setup currently

```
AWARDS
2017
 - Product 1
 - Product 2
 - Product 3
2016
 - Product 1
 - Product 2
 - Product 3
2015
 - Product 1
 - Product 2
 - Product 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need  many-to-many relationships between your entities.
You should try **ACF** plugin, it gives you the possibility to easely create those type of relationships:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/